# Netbeans web application won't start on Windows 7

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, windows-7

At work I'm using Netbeans with Tomcat 6 without any problem. Tomcat isn't bundled to netbeans but the zip version, I have added it to IDE later. However at home neither Tomcat nor Glassfish won't start. I also tried uninstalling the current Netbeans and installing tomcat/glassfish bundled version. A blank page loaded to the browser first, after several seconds Firefos says "server responds too late".

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so others will know there is a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem and I want to share: I tried 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of localhost:8080 and it worked. Then in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc directory edited the hosts file. For some reason the line was commented and there is an explanation like this:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost (uncommented this line)
```